# Kubernetes external connection problems

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have 2 services (1 -- httpd + php, 2 -- go gin). They have same configuration. The problem is that I can connect externally only to one of these, while the second one throws error, but if I connect from within cluster, all is ok. I deploy them through helm using 1 base chart for each.

### IPs

192.168.49.1 -- abc. port: 9999
192.168.49.2 -- my-k8s-app. port: 80

### Error

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.49.1 port 9999 after 0 ms: Couldn't connect to server
```

### Values.yaml

```
abc:
  image: regretto/gateway:latest
  port: 9999
  service:
    type: LoadBalancer
    externalPort: 9999

my-k8s-app:
  image: regretto/myk8sapp:latest
  port: 80
  service:
    type: LoadBalancer
    externalPort: 8080
```

### service.yml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: "{{ .Chart.Name | lower | replace "_" "-"}}"
  labels:
    proj: "{{ .Release.Name }}"
    slave_microservice: "{{ .Chart.Name | lower | replace "_" "-" }}"
spec:
  type: {{default "ClusterIP" .Values.service.type}}
  ports:
    - port: {{ .Values.port }}
      NodePort: {{ default .Values.port .Values.service.externalPort }}
      protocol: {{default "TCP" .Values.service.protocol}}
  selector:
    app: {{.Chart.Name | lower | replace "_" "-"}}
```

### deployment.yml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: "{{ .Chart.Name | lower | replace "_" "-"}}"
  labels:
    proj: "{{ .Release.Name | lower}}"
    app: {{ .Chart.Name | lower | replace "_" "-" }}
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.hpa.minReplicas }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      proj: "{{ .Release.Name | lower}}"
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        proj: "{{ .Release.Name | lower }}"
        app: "{{ .Chart.Name | lower | replace "_" "-"}}"
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: {{ .Chart.Name | lower | replace "_" "-"}}
          image: {{ tpl .Values.image . }}
          imagePullPolicy: {{ default "Always" .Values.pull_policy }}
          ports:
            - containerPort: {{ .Values.port }}
          args: {{ toYaml .Values.args | nindent 12}}
```